# How can I achieve this transparency effect using css?

Tags: html, css, psd

[image]

This design is created in photoshop and I'm trying to convert to html and css.
I have a background image (with the green lights), an overlay with reduced opacity and some text with an icon positioned at the center. How can I attain the effect shown below in html and css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here!

Basically you can create a transparent round shape with a big white (or black) border!

```
background: transparent;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 1000px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/thct2ym0/)

Answer (score 5):

you could apply a `border-radius` to the inner element and a `box-shadow` like so:

> [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vavmrp)

```
div {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: url(...) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

p {
    border-radius: 50%;

    /* add responsive behaviour */
    height : 60vw;
    width  : 60vw;

    /* but limit its max-height/width */
    max-height : 400px;
    max-width  : 400px;

    /* apply a gray shadow outside */
    box-shadow : 0 0 0 50vmax rgba(255,255,255, .4);
}
```

`50vmax` is a shadow spread wide enough and middle alignment can be done e.g. via [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) positioning. Just adjust the alpha value of the shadow (or the color) as you prefer.

---

**Final result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
  }

.overlay {
      top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-500px;
    margin-left:-500px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;  
    border-style: solid;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    z-index:999;
    pointer-events:none;
    border: 400px solid rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```